# How do i set pagination to a JQgrid after inserting data

Tags: jqgrid, pagination

I have a JQgrid with datatype set to local and i have disabled pagination.Is there anyway to enable pagination after populating data. I have disabled pagination at first as the empty JQGrid shows page 1 of 0.

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:pager#properties

```
jQuery("#grid_id").setGridParam({pager:'#gridpager'}).trigger("reloadGrid");
```